# How to create a XML template?

Tags: python, xml, templates

i have 2 Python scripts that write to a same XML file. i'm using Python2.5 and WinXP.
How can I create a template so that the XML file isn't overwritten when I run another Python script. It will only updates the section in the XML with value. For eg:XML template as below:

```
<Test>
 <Default>
   <Value>1</Value> 
   <Link_Status>0</Link_Status> 
   <Lane_Status>1</Lane_Status> 
 </Default>
 <Settings>
  <Point>4</Point> 
  <Delay>1</Delay> 
 </Settings>
</Test>
```

i want default.py to update to the Default section and Settings.py to update the Settings section. appreciate your advice. tq

Default.py code:

```
import elementtree.ElementTree as ET 

root=ET.Element("Test")
head1=ET.SubElement(root,"Default")
title=ET.SubElement(head1,"Value")
title.text="1"

title=ET.SubElement(head1,"Link_Status")
title.text="0"

title=ET.SubElement(head1,"Lane_Status")
title.text="1"

tree=ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write("C:\Python25\myscript\cmm\\config.xml")
```

Settings.py code:

```
import elementtree.ElementTree as ET

root=ET.Element("Test")
head2=ET.SubElement(root,"Settings")
title=ET.SubElement(head2,"Point")
title.text=("4")

title=ET.SubElement(head2,"Delay")
title.text=("1")

tree=ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write("C:\Python25\myscript\cmm\\config.xml")
```

Comment: Please format your source code properly!

Comment: sorry for the display. didnt know how to post just now. now i have learnt it and re-edited the posting. :)

Comment: "How can I create a template so that the XML file isn't overwritten when I run another Python script."  Wow.  That makes almost no sense.  If you don't want to override the file, don't open it in `"w"` mode.  A template has **nothing** to do with file overwriting.

Comment: @S.Lott I'm sure your great at parties.. jeez, lol

Answer (score 1):

Read and just update the specific section instead of the whole file, like below

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
with open("test.xml") as f:
    root = ET.parse( f ).getroot()

# update <Default>
root.remove( root.find("./Default") )

defaultNode = ET.SubElement(root,"Default")
ET.SubElement(defaultNode,"Value").text = "999"
ET.SubElement(defaultNode,"Link_Status").text = "888"
ET.SubElement(defaultNode,"Lane_Status").text = "777"

with open("test.xml" , "w" ) as f:
    f.write( ET.tostring( root ) )
```

----EDIT TO ADD NEW--

Actually, I just want to show you the way that you can just read in the file and update some section and then write them out without have to create a new xml content every time. OK, if your xml structure is static, you can just update the specific text by locating it with XPATH, maybe the following one can solve your little issues.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
with open("test.xml") as f:
root = ET.parse( f ).getroot()

# update <Default>
root.find("./Default/Value").text = "999"
root.find("./Default/Link_Status").text = "888"
root.find("./Default/Lane_Status").text = "777"

with open("test.xml" , "w" ) as f:
    f.write( ET.tostring( root ) )
```

BTW,
As regards to the first example, if I do not remove the  before adding a new one, you will get two  node under , that's is why I use remove firstly to remove the old one and create a new one.

Comment: hi, great. this seems to work! could you pls explain what does root.remove line code mean? root find is to find the Default word but why does the root.remove mean? tq

Comment: i also notice that everytime i run the script, the latest update in the xml will happen to the bottom. For eg: If i run the Default.py, it will update the Default section of the XML at the bottom. The Settings will be on top of the XML. When i run Settings.py, then the Setting section will appear at the bottom while the Default is on top. Is there a way to prevent this ie to fix it Default on top and Settings at the bottom. tq

Comment: Add a new script for you, that should be what you want :D